# How to make terniary statement work in for-loop?

Tags: ruby

I want to add 366 to the amount of days if it is divisible by 4, and 365 if not. Why does

```
amountOfDays = 0
for i in 0..100
    i % 4 == 0 ? amountOfdays += 366 :  amountOfdays += 365
end
```

not work? It says `undefined method + for nil:NilClass`.

And how can I get it to work?

Comment: I think you mean "and 365 if not."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your code. On the top you set `amountOfDays` (capital D), then you use `amountOfdays`. Ruby initializes the variable to `nil`, since it is being assigned to (yes, it's a bit weird in this case). Example:

```
a += 10
# NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Instead of

```
a + 10
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
```

Which would be a bit easier to diagnose.

Also, you are using the `(i % 4)` expression as it returned a boolean, but it returns a number. In ruby, everything but `false` and `nil` evaluates to `true` ("truthy", actually), so your condition is never false.

At last, since you are using ternaries, you might as well use the fact that they are expressions:

```
amountOfDays = 0
for i in 0..100
  amountOfDays += (i % 4) == 0 ? 366 : 365
end
```

And, if you want to be a bit more idiomatic (it's very rare to use a `for` loop in ruby):

```
amount_of_days = (0..100).map { |year| year % 4 == 0 ? 366 : 365 }.reduce(:+)
```

Comment: Renato, in your last line, there's no need for `map`; using `reduce` alone is cleaner and faster.

Comment: I know there's no need, but I disagree that it is clearer. I personally prefer to separate transforming the values from combining them.

Comment: Thanks Renato. I find this reduce function a strange one. I've seen `inject(:+)` which summed everything in the array (very nice), and `reduce(:+)` in this case adds the values as well? /edit I see they are the same thing. :-) Question (2): can you explain how reduce can take two parameters in Arup's way `number_of_days = (0..100).reduce(0) { |tot,i| tot + ((i%4 == 0) ? 366 : 365) } `?

Comment: `inject` and `reduce` are two names for the same method, like `map` and `collect`, `[]` and `slice`, etc.

Comment: Yes, inject and reduce are the same method! I tend to use reduce more because it's more common in other languages

Comment: @CarySwoveland Why does `puts "b\`qx?rvnudk\`mc-bnl".chars.map(&:succ).join` work? ;-) / I think `chars` turns them in characters, maps them to `&:succ` which I do not understand, and then joins them into a string?

Comment: user2609980, the explanation for that (my email address) will have to wait for another day, as this is Renato's space.

Answer (score 3):

Because you defined `amountOfDays = 0` not, `amountOfdays = 0`. Both are different variables. May be a *Typo*. Use any one out of those in all cases.

Like

```
amountOfdays = 0
for i in 0..100
    (i % 4 == 0) ? amountOfdays += 366 :  amountOfdays += 365
end
```

Correct naming would be in Ruby - `amount_of_days` instead of `amountOfdays`. Or grammatically more sound `number_of_days`.

In more Ruby way -

```
number_of_days = (0..100).reduce(0) { |tot,i| tot + ((i%4 == 0) ? 366 : 365) } 
#=> 36891
```

Comment: Jeez this took me some time :=) I'm somewhat new to Ruby and used to static typed languages with IDE. Sublime Text does not give the red curly things. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: thanks a lot for the naming conventions and the "more Ruby way" - way more elegant!

Comment: How can this reduce(0) with a double argument lambda expression (?) work? I'll look it up in the API. /edit. hmm cannot find it. What I imagine that it means is: reduce (has to do with summing, that is in the Apidock), so 0 to 100 are added from 0-index(the (0) after reduce) and based on the total (tot) and index (i) 366 (if divisible by 4) or 365 (if not) is added to the totat.

Comment: And (2) I have this code: `for i in 0..number_of_days
 if (i % 7 == 0)
  sundays.push(i)
 end
end`. I can imagine that I can rewrite this pushing of a number into the array if it is divisible by seven in a more "Ruby way" as well.

Comment: As it is now 3:30am where @Arup lives in India, he may be taking a short break. Perhaps I can answer your questions. I expect you've already answered the first one: that [Enumerable#reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) is the same as Enumerable#reduce. I'll answer your question #2 in a separate comment.

Comment: Regarding your question #2, I'll give you three answers for the price of one, in my declining order of preference: (1) `(0..number_of_days).step(7).to_a` (2) `0.upto(number_of_days).each_with_object([]) { |i,days| (days << i) if i%7==0 }` (3) `0.upto(number_of_days).reduce([]) { |days,i| (days << i) if i%7==0; days }`.  I suggest you read up on Ruby's [naming convention](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_names.html).

Comment: user2609980, you asked how `number_of_days = (0..100).reduce(0) { |tot,i| tot + ((i%4 == 0) ? 366 : 365) }` works.  The block variable `tot` is is initially assigned the value of `reduce`'s argument.  At each iteration, `tot + ((i%4 == 0) ? 366 : 365)` is assigned to `tot` and (being the last statement in the block) is returned to `reduce` (aka `inject`) and then passed into the block for the next iteration.  After all elements of the receiver `(0..100)` have been enumerated, the value of `tot` is returned.  Check the docs for `Enumerable#reduce` for the case where no argument is specified.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you Cary. For such detailed explanation.